# eliminar duplicados de arraylist en android no me funciona

Tags: java, android-studio

hola tengo una funcion en donde obtengo un listado de rias, que provienen de otro arraylist de poligonos. De modo que cada poligono tiene asociada una ria y lo que hago es obtener el listado de todas las rias. Pero quiero eliminar los duplicados, es decir que no haya rias repetidas. Para ello utilizo este codigo:

```
Set<Ria> set = new HashSet<>(r);
        r.clear();
        r.addAll(set);
```

Pero no me esta funcionando. Si muestro el listado del arraylist r, de esta manera:

```
for(Ria ria:r)
        {
            Log.i("holas",ria.getNombre());
        }
```

me sigue mostrando rias repetidas.
Esta es la funcion completa:

```
public ArrayList<Ria> obtenerRias()
{
    ArrayList<Ria> r = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Poligono p:poligonos)
    {
        Ria ria=new Ria(p.getRia());
            r.add(ria);
    }

    Set<Ria> set = new HashSet<>(r);
    r.clear();
    r.addAll(set);
    for(Ria ria:r)
    {
        Log.i("hola",ria.getNombre());
    }
    return r;
}
```

y esta es la clase Ria:

```
public class Ria implements Comparable<Ria>{
    private String nombre;

    public Ria() {
    }

    public Ria(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Ria ria) {
        if(this.nombre.equals(ria.getNombre()))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }

}
```

y esta la clase poligono:

```
public class Poligono {
    private String nombre;
    private String ria;
    private boolean flag;

    public Poligono() {
    }

    public Poligono(String nombre, String ria, boolean flag) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.ria = ria;
        this.flag = flag;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getRia() {
        return ria;
    }

    public void setRia(String ria) {
        this.ria = ria;
    }

    public boolean isFlag() {
        return flag;
    }

    public void setFlag(boolean flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }
}
```

Comment: Has sobreescrito el método `compareTo` de tu clase `Ria`? Porque si no lo haces, por defecto dos objetos son diferentes si su dirección de memoria es diferente... Aunque sus campos sean idénticos, crear dos objetos con los mismos campos dará como resultado dos objetos *"diferentes"*. Para evitar eso se sobreescribe el método `compareTo`, y ahí ya tú eliges cómo diferenciar un objeto del otro.

Comment: ya he sobreescrito el metodo `compareTo`, (ya he editado mi primer post y he añadido la clase Ria donde se sobreescribe el `compareTo`). Pero sigue sin eliminarme los repetidos.

Comment: Me parece que el problema puede estar en tu objeto poligono, agregalo por favor!

Comment: ya la he agregado.

Answer (score 0):

Según [la documentación del método add de java.util.HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add(E)), el método de comparación utilizado es `equals`, el cual está definido inicialmente por la clase `java.lang.Object` y debes redefinir.

```java
public class Ria implements Comparable<Ria>{
    private String nombre;

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        // si no es Ria no son iguales
        if (!(other instanceof Ria)) {
            return false;
        }

        Ria rother = (Ria) other;
        return nombre.equals(rother.getNombre());
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: he probado con eso y sigue mostrandome los repetidos. Ademas he puesto un `Log.i()` en el metodo sobreescrito y no se muestra con lo cual deduzco que nunca entra en el metodo sobreescrito.